# Is there a convenient way to create spatial index with Sqlalchemy or Geoalchemy?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, geospatial

Yesterday someone told me that Geoalchemy was a good choice to support spatial extensions if I want to use Sqlalchemy. It really did good. Thanks for him a lot.

But I have not found a convenient way to create spatial index with Geoalchemy. Must I run this SQL directly?

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX sp_index ON my_class (
geom_col
);
```

Is there a convenient way to do it without directly writing the SQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When creating a table with `table.create()` GeoAlchemy will automatically create an index for the geometry column.

Also, SQLAlchemy `Index` instances have a `create` method. See the "Indexes" section in http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/schema.html#metadata-constraints. I'm not sure if you'll be able to create a spatial index in MySQL with that but it's worth a try.

Comment: It seems that the index wasn't created automatically. Would you please give a detailed example?

Answer (score 0):

With GeoAlchemy, there are 2 steps you should take to create Spatial Index on the geometry column

- add attr 'spatial_index' to the geometry column
- Call the GeometryDDL extension

Example:

```py
# note that spatial_index will set the column to not null 
class Building(Base):
    geom = GeometryColumn(Point(2, spatial_index=True))

GeometryDDL(Building.__table__)
```