# MySQL spatial index with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, spatial, ddl

There is a nice example in sqlalchemy docs on how to define and use `Geometry` column in sqlalchemy:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#applying-sql-level-bind-result-processing

However, spatial indexes aren't mentioned anywhere in the docs.
So, how can I define a `SPATIAL INDEX` with sqlalchemy?

P.S.
There is already a an old question about this: [Is there a convenient way to create spatial index with Sqlalchemy or Geoalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462455/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-create-spatial-index-with-sqlalchemy-or-geoalchemy), but I refuse to use GeoAlchemy that has been abandoned "in early stage of development" two years ago, so this is a different question, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just execute the DDL for it:

```
 engine.execute("CREATE SPATIAL INDEX sp_index ON geom (g)")
```

if you'd like to associate this command with some table, use [DDL](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/ddl.html?highlight=ddl#sqlalchemy.schema.DDL):

```
from sqlalchemy import event, DDL

event.listen(some_table, 'after_create', DDL("CREATE SPATIAL INDEX sp_index ON geom (g)"))
```

Comment: Sure, that's what I did after researching events. Shouldn't this be a mysql specific option for `Index` though?